# Arreglos unidimensionales en lenguaje c

Tags: c

Tengo que captura la estatura de 10 elementos, tiene que decir cual es el mayor y el menor y sacar el promedio, pero tengo problemas para sacar el mínimo y el promedio.

***Código***

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<conio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    int x[10]; 
    int i,j,a; 
    int max;
    int min;
    int prom,suma=0;
    /* Capturando los valores del arreglo */ 
    for (i=0; i <10; i=i+1) 
    { 
        printf("Capture valor estatura: [%d]: ", i+1); 
        scanf("%d",&x[i]); 
    } 
    /* Ordenando el arreglo */ 
    for (i=0; i <10; i=i+1) 
    for (j=0; j <10; j=j+1) 
    if ( x[i] < x[j] ) 
    { 
        a= x[i]; 
        x[i]=x[j]; 
        x[j]=a; 
    } 
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {

        if (x[i] > max)
        { 
            max = x[i];
        } 
        else if (x[i] < max)
        {
            min = x[i];
        } 
    }

    printf("Estatura maxima es: %d  Estatura minima es: %d \n",max,min);

    /* Desplegando el contenido del archivo */ 
    for(i=0; i <10; i=i+1) 
    printf(" %d", x[i]); 

    suma=suma+x[i];
    prom=suma/10;

    printf("\nPromedio estaturas: %d",prom);

    getch(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no es necesario que ordenes el arreglo para que saques el máximo, mínimo y el promedio. con solo utilizar una variable que puedas comparar con los elementos del arreglo es suficiente.

te presento mi siguiente código

## include

## include

int main() 
{ 
    int x[10]; 
    int i; 
    int max;
    int min;
    float suma=0;
    float promedio;

```
/* Capturando los valores del arreglo */ 
for (i=0; i <10; i++) 
{ 
    printf("Capture valor estatura: [%d]: ", i+1); 
    scanf("%d",&x[i]); 
}


//obteniendo el maximo

max = x[0];  //asigno el primer elemento del arreglo a la variable max

for (i=0;i<9;i++){

    if (max < x[i+1]) //si el valor almacenado en max es menor que el siguiente elemento del arreglo entonces max sera ese valor siguiente
    max=x[i+1];

}


//obteniedo el minimo

min = x[0];  //asigno el primer elemento del arreglo a la variable min

for (i=0;i<9;i++){

    if (min > x[i+1])//si el valor almacenado en min es mayor que el siguiente elemento del arreglo entonces min sera ese valor siguiente
    min=x[i+1];
}

printf("El valor maximo es: %d\n",max);
printf("El valor minimo es: %d\n",min);


//obteniendo el promedio

for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    suma = suma + x[i]; //Suma todos los elementos del arreglo y lo guarda en la variable suma
}

promedio = suma/10; //divide la suma de todos los elementos del arreglo entre la cantidad de elementos
printf("El promedio es: %.2f",promedio);
```

}

Te dejo algunos tips de mi código

1. Declara las variable sumar y promedio como float, ya que si la declaras como int, al momento de obtener el resultado no imprimirá con cifras decimales.
2. Para imprimir la cantidad de cifras decimales que desees, colocar %.2f como se muestra en mi código. Si deseas 3 cifras decimales solo debes colocar %.3f, si deseas 4 cifras decimales colocar %.4f y así sucesivamente.
3. En el Ciclo **for** puedes usar **i++** en lugar de **i= i+1** para el incremento.
   for (i=0; i <10; i++)

Answer (score 0):

Primero no es necesario ordenar el arreglo,

En el **for** de buscar **min** y **max**, escribistes:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
```

Debe ser así, para no desbordar el vector.

```
for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
```

El problema del menor, esta en el **if** siguiente, usas el **max**:

```
else if (x[i] < max)
{
    min = x[i];
}
```

Debe ser, usando el **min**:

```
else if (x[i] < min)
{
    min = x[i];
}
```

Y el problema del promedio, es porque no haces bien la suma, porque el **for** de la suma, no suma, sólo imprime:

El código yo lo haría así:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main() 
{
    int x[10];
    int i;
    int max;
    int min;
    int prom,suma;
    // Capturando los valores del arreglo
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("Capture valor estatura: [%d]: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d",&x[i]);
    }
    // Buscar mínimo, máximo, y calcular suma
    min = x[0];
    max = x[0];
    suma = x[0];
    for(i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if(x[i] > max)
        {
            max = x[i];
        }
        else if(x[i] < min)
        {
            min = x[i];
        }
        suma += x[i];
    }
    // Calcular promedio
    prom = suma/10;

    printf("\n");
    printf("Estatura maxima es: %d  Estatura minima es: %d \n", max, min);
    printf("Promedio estaturas: %d\n", prom);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```